# Are companies actively using the "Jobs" features?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I've been using the "Jobs" product for around 1 year by now, and I can say I'm really happy about the results I have got until now, however there's something bugging me recently:

I've applied and/or sent questions for a job to about 10 companies using Jobs. From all these attempts I got a reply from the targeted company only once or twice. I know that it may be perfectly normal, since I know my resumé is not that great, but there's something else about it: When I applied for jobs directly on the companies websites I got an answer on almost every resumé sent, even if it's just to reject my application.

So here is my question: Are the majority of companies actively using Jobs to hire people, or it's just that I'm not fit for so many companies out there?

The answer can be either using an actual data for the website, or even your own experiences about this whole thing.

Since I've made this post I have applied for a same position on a company using two methods: Jobs application and company website (two days later). Just received an email notification about the job rejection of my website application. The Jobs one still no response.

Comment: What country were the companies in that you applied to? In some countries, it is perfectly normal not to send out rejections at all (unless there was some more back and forth, interviews, etc.)

Comment: @Pekka, mainly European countries. The same for the companies I've applied outside the site.

Comment: Wow, you get notified of rejections, ever? I'm envious.

Comment: No, usually I do not get any notification, the point is: There are more notifications from companies that receive applications directly from their websites. I just want to know why this happens, or if it is just a misconception of mine.

Comment: In Germany it is common to send rejections. In doubt it is an automatically generated electronic message, when the job is no longer vacant to all people who applied to that job.

Comment: I believe you just got lucky, in my case I've applied to lot of jobs on StackOverflow and got no rejection, nor approval, which is hurt :-)

Comment: I am not sure about other countries, but here in India it is a common practice to not send any rejection emails. You apply for the job the companies do not notify you at all. If I don't get any follow up call for a week, it means that they are not interested *(with few exceptions. There are few occasions in which I received call after around 4 months :/)*

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the input, but the core question here is wether or not the companies are using Jobs. I mean, I know there are some countries that do not send rejection notifications, but the real point is: usually I'm getting more return (acception or rejection for a hire proccess) than I get from the companies here.

Comment: @ImamAssidiqqi well your own profile description says you are a dummy […].

Comment: @NathanTuggy I've always gotten answers back from european job applications, but ever from american companies.

Comment: The companies pay quite some money for their job listings, so I'd say the will use it very actively.

Comment: @Bonifacio are the European countries you apply to Portugal or Spain? In these it's common not so send rejections.

Comment: @J.A.I.L.usually no. So far I've tried Netherlands, Germany, Ireland, Spain and some others I do not remember now.

Comment: Based on my conversations with job applicants, people do get responses through SO - though this varies based on the individual and company. We do want to do a better job encouraging companies to respond, but for now it isn't prioritized.