# "We really like this job for you" annoying emails

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I just received an unsolicited email from Stack Overflow Careers that listed a job offer and indicated I would have liked it. However the compensation package is half of what I had set up in my job preferences, so why am I even receiving this?

Comment: Not really an answer, but see [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906)

Comment: Was it in your hometown?  I received a similar inappropriate email for a job in my home town.  But  junior, low pay, and not what I do.  Honest matching is difficult, much easier to mismarket email and eat up SO's good reputation for temporary metrics gains.

Comment: I don't even receive any emails. Employers also don't reply to my applications. It seems I'm a ghost.

Comment: @undefined Same feeling.

Comment: @undefined so you suggest he changes his name to null?

Comment: @undefined Username checks out.

Comment: @GeorgeRappel I use my full real name in official letters. There are 2 fields: "Display name" and "Full name" which has this caption: "How you appear to employers and other users when you share your Developer Story." I think the problem is my nationality.

Comment: I too recently received one of these which was completely irrelevant which got to me change my email settings. First time I have ever been annoyed be an SO/SE email.

Comment: I also feel like "We really like this job for you" is oddly phrased. "We really think you'll like this job" is probably better, but will (per this question) probably often be wrong ;).

Comment: @bono Are they offering a better package?

Comment: I received a similar email -- really nice salary range, but for a senior level job using a programming language I've never used or listed anywhere on any version of my resume, let alone in my job search query. Tempting, but ...

Comment: @MeghanArmes - no self-respecting (?) recruiter would *ever* allow a candidate's lack of knowledge deter him from presenting that candidate for a job :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis ha :) "I have no experience with $language, BUT I'm happy to learn as I go." That usually opens all kinds of doors ... exit doors ...

Comment: @undefined The `if (username !== "undefined") writeJobInvitationTo(username);` bug will be fixed in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @MeghanArmes - back in the dark ages (1987) I was a contractor, and went to an interview with one of our body-slammers. We got there and he pulled "my" resume' and started telling the client manager about how I was an expert on VMS and knew all about C on VMS and etc and blah and...I said, "Let me see that". I pulled the resume' out of his hand, looked at it, and saw a work of fiction. I quietly said, "I'm afraid there's been some mistake. I have no experience on VMS but I'm a quick study".  Recruiter was *furious* - but I.GOT.THE.GIG! Client said, "You were the only one who was honest". :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis I love it! That's amazing! Kudos to you for having a backbone, and kudos to the client for valuing your honesty.

Comment: @MeghanArmes - I might not have minded so much if he'd bothered to tell me about his "creative rewrite" of my resume' - at least then we would have been on the same page.

Comment: @BobJarvis I've heard of recruiters getting "creative" with resumes but haven't seen it firsthand myself -- I wonder what he thought you were going to do, just go along with it without skipping a beat?

Comment: @MeghanArmes - I think that was pretty much the expectation. I think I was supposed to squirm uncomfortably in my chair and mumble "Yeah...expert...been doin' that for years..." or something like that. After the interview we walked back to his car and he snarled something like, "Don't you **ever** do that to me again!". I fired back, "Don't YOU ever do something like that to ME again!", and we had a nice tense ride back to the office. Two days later he stumbled into the bullpen and said, "I don't believe it. You got the gig!". Hey - honesty - what a concept! :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis that's incredible :) The guy had no shame! I wonder if that was just accepted procedure at his office.

Comment: @MarkWragg Maybe it's a regional thing? I've heard and read, "I like X for you" before. Not more often than your suggestion, but it's a thing.

Comment: @BobJarvis That story reminded of this https://youtu.be/oKyV-l8i5lg?t=2m35s :)

Comment: @undefined, I can [relate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344130/are-companies-actively-using-the-jobs-features) with you

Comment: @Marco13: seems to be the right time to change the user name to [bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)…

Comment: Happened to me too just now.  Got an email about a [tag:php]/[tag:node.js]/[tag:c++] job where my rep points are a whopping 102/8/12, mainly from questions which were also coincidentally about [tag:bash] or [tag:regex] where I have at least *some sort of* presence. Which sort of suggests a tweak -- ignore my rep in tags which were pulled in by one of the tags I have a high score in.

Comment: Just received one for a position as a "Product Operations Engineer" that has to work with python. i hate python with a passion, and it's in my "i prefer not to work with" list right here on SO.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. First, [as Michelle said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354588/stack-overflow-career-we-really-like-this-job-for-you-annoying-emails#comment501286_354588), you can [update your email preferences here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) (this particular email is sent from the "Recommended Jobs" bucket) or you can also opt-out with one click from the footer of the email you received.

I just wanted to let you know that we've discussed internally how to improve this email. We're thinking about considering salary a stronger signal. As as result we have decided to only recommend jobs that:

1. Pay what you're asking on your match preferences or more (if you have entered a number there)
2. The seniorities on the job overlap on the ones on your match preferences (if you have entered a minimum and/or maximum there)

Thanks for helping us build a better product!

Comment: The challenge, I think, is I have a sort of sliding scale thing - for a job I can commute to in about the same amount of time, I want a similar salary. But if I have to commute further, that goes up. And if I have to relocate, that's another jump (that's _sometimes_ offset by cost of living). But even for the most awesome job in the world - I'll rarely be able  to take a pay _cut_, unless it was a real 'change your life' sort of thing (and included a significant reduction in cost of living too). I'm not sure how you could factor this in to a job-search though.

Comment: This is not status-completed. I have never expressed an interest in receiving job spam emails from you guys and just got one. Every last radio button on the 'Job Match Preferences' for my account is unchecked. If you want me to think you're going the Facebook route with a million incessant stupid policy changes to jump through constantly until I just walk away, you are doing a good job.

Comment: @reisio the reason why I marked this [meta-tag:status-completed] is because the OP reported a bug (the recommended job was outside what he set up in his matching preferences) that is now resolved. In your case, if you don't want to ever receive emails from the /jobs team, you should opt out of the [Recommended Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) email bucket if you haven't done so. We're putting serious effort into doing email right. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: You should not in the first place send me unsolicited spam suggesting my current situation is lousy and requires replacement. You shouldn't send me spam of any kind. Especially because I never asked you to. Opt out? Out? You want me to opt out of something I never asked for, rather than opting in to something? We'll see how you guys do at opting out of having made an enemy for life.

Comment: @reisio that is unrelated to the OP's question. Feel free to write a new question and we'll be happy to talk about our reasoning and how we're trying to target our emails in a way that's useful for our users. It doesn't mean we get it right every time, but I'm happy to share details on how we're doing that

Comment: If your reasoning is that you made a mistake in emailing me an offensive unsolicited email and are fixing your end so it won't happen again, then kudos to you. Otherwise, the only "reasoning" for making people opt out of things is being greedy and evil. Why would I care about talking to you about how you are those things—it is in this case already apparent.

Comment: If you received an offensive email, please send it my way (my email address is on my profile) and I'll be happy to look into that. If you don't choose "not interested in jobs" or don't opt out of the "Recommended Jobs" bucket, I can almost guarantee you will receive new emails. The bug the OP reported was that the job was good but paying less than what he set up on his matching preferences, and that's the bug I fixed.

Comment: Enemy for life, then. Thanks for making the choice straightforward. (When you walk up to someone and, unprompted, without solicitation, not knowing the state of their contentedness say to them that they could do better about anything they're doing, you are being offensive.)

Answer (score -5):

I have an idea how you could improve these emails. Stop sending them.

And yes I know I can turn them off for myself, but I can't turn them off for my staff who are now all getting offers to poach them in their company emails!!!!!!

Seems like it might be time to stop using SO entirely.

Comment: There is an option in "Job match preferences" (under profile settings) where you can say you are "Not interested in jobs". Checking that option blocks all emails about job offers. Maybe your staff wants to leave, or maybe they forgot to change the setting. Basically, it isn't SO's fault, it is not changing that one checkbox in settings. You can also block specific emails (or filter them) as said in the accepted answer

Comment: No, they are tired of them too, but they don't have time to go looking for settings on every app they use to stop spammy messages. They also don't want to leave, they're very happy thank you very much, but getting constant emails about other jobs while they're working for us is just bad for everybody. Surely you all can see that? I imagine the 6 people who voted me down are recruitment agents.